# Clarity does not give insights in traffic when combined with Viva connection?

Tags: clarity

I want to get more user insights on a Sharepoint website I made. When users go directly through the webpage clarity works perfect to show all the tracking. When the users go through a viva connection button on their Teams to the Sharepoint website the tracking does not work properly. Numbers are not accurate and once they click on buttons on Sharepoint the tracking stops. Is this normal? or is there a workaround to still get a good insight in the users?

looked through answers did not find them.